# req.body empty for textarea in http form (Using Express)

Tags: javascript, html, http, express, pug

I have the following form to have the user upload a file and submit text:

```
form(action='/createpost' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post' id="imgForm")
    input(type='file' name='imgPath' size = "60")
    br
    textarea(name="postText" form="imgForm") Enter your post text here...
    br
    input(type='submit' value="Submit")
```

When I run this:

```
router.post('/createpost', function(req,res){
  console.log("POST FORM BODY", req.body.postText);
  res.end();
});
```

I get `undefined` in the console. How do I get the value of the input inside textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part in the form and see if it works.  I think servers interpret data sent in multipart differently.

I don't know if I understand what `enctype="multipart/form-data"` does, but I'd use it when uploading a file from a form and the node module [multiparty](https://npmjs.org/packages/multiparty)

Comment: That worked! Thanks :) I had copied that form code from another example since I wasn't sure how to have users upload files

Comment: that's excellent @prcbass - If that has solved your problem marked as the accepted answer is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Will do, can't accept your response as an answer for another 5 minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this answer, if you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
You have to use a middleware that can handle files, which body-parser cannot. A popular option is multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer